# Hide Span Class from Certain Page

Tags: css, code

I'm trying to hide a span class from certain page (Not all pages)
Below is the span I want to hide

```
<span class="wpte-bf-reg-price">
```

The page I want to hide the above span class is

```
post=5694
```

I'd figured something like this would work but it's not working.

```
.page-id-5694 #wpte-bf-reg-price {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the `#` to a `.` since the span has a class and not an ID?